# Drawing an arrow with an outline

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to draw multiple arrows with a colored outline on a form, so far I'm using the following code:

```
Pen arrow_pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(r, g, b), 8);
arrow_pen.EndCap = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.LineCap.ArrowAnchor;
GraphicsPath arrow = new GraphicsPath();
        arrow.AddLine(
            coordinates1,
            coordinates2,
            coordinates3,
            coordinates4
            );
obj.DrawPath(arrow_pen, arrow);
obj.FillPath(Brushes.White, arrow);
arrow.Dispose();
arrow_pen.Dispose();
```

It draws the outline for the arrow, but then it dosent fill the path with white (obj.FillPath does nothing), am I missing something or am I doing this the wrong way?

Comment: `obj` is definitely of type `Graphics` is it?

Comment: its definded like this:  `using (Graphics obj = this.CreateGraphics())`

Comment: Use AddPolygon() instead.  Never use CreateGraphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Fills the **interior** of a GraphicsPath.

Your path is only a single line and not closed. Therefore, according to the documentation:

> If the path represented by the path parameter is not closed, an additional segment is added from the last point to the first point to close the path.

So now you have two identical lines spanning an area of exactly nothing. That area is filled but you cannot see it, as it's zero pixels wide. You need to define a closed graph that has an area greater than zero to actually fill something.

Comment: Any other way of drawing an arrow, so I can fill it, gave me only results that could be defined as abstract art, so I went the dumb way and drew a bigger black arrow and then a smaller colored one over it, bit more work but works like a charm.